# NodeJS - Parse large collection with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bigdata

I have a collection in my mongodb that has around 10 Mio documents. I want to traverse all of them to change some fields. Taking all at once crashes the program since it is too much data, and using limit like following

```
MyModel.find({/* condition... */}).limit(500).exec()
```

is problematic since the same documents are returned every time again since my modification does not change the condition.

Can anybody give me a hint how I can incrementally traverse/modify the entire collection?

Comment: I think you should take a look at `skip` aggregate of mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin has outlined two valid options.

Another option would be to essentially paginate. If you sort by `_id` and keep querying for a larger `_id` you can keep your exact same logic. Something like:

```
var lastId = new ObjectId();
MyModel.find({/* condition... */, _id: {$gt: lastId}}).sort({_id: 
1}).limit(500).exec(function(err, records){
    // Your logic
    lastId = records[records.length - 1]._id;
})
```

You'd just need to wrap the function in some sort of asynchronous `while` loop and make sure you exit once you don't receive 500 records.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `Model.update` method? See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html. The way it works, is you specify a query, and an update statement, and it searches for all documents matching the query and then applies the update to each document. E.g.

```
const query = {};
const update = {$set: {name: "Bob"}};
const options = {};
Model.update(query, update, options, callback);
```

If you really must use find-then-update, you probably want to use a cursor, which will ensure the set of documents are streamed rather than fully realized in memory at once:

```
const cursor = Model.find(query).cursor()
cursor.on('data', function(doc) {});
cursor.on('close', callback);
```